# I want to store more than one 2d arrays in file using python

Tags: python, numpy

I am using python 2.7. I tried to store 2d arrays in file, but it stored only recent value. Suppose if I enter values for 3 arrays which are of 4 rows and two columns then it just store recent single value which i entered for last array. I used numpy for taking input for array. I tried this code:

```
import numpy as np
from math import *

def main ():
    i_p = input("\n Enter number of input patterns:")
    out = raw_input("\n Enter number of output nodes:")
    hidden = raw_input("\n Enter number of hidden layers:")
    print 'Patterns:'
    for p in range(0,i_p):
        print "z[%d]"%p

        rows=input("Enter no of rows:")
        cols=input("Enter no of coloumns:")
        ff=open('array.txt','w')
        for r in range(0,rows):
            for c in range(0,cols):
                z=np.matrix(input())
                ff.write(z)
                np.savetxt('array.txt',z)



if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Ident your code properly, please

Comment: You are opening your file (with the same file name) inside a for loop. Every time the loop runs, the file will be overwritten with new content.

Comment: so how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Your

```
np.savetxt('array.txt',z)
```

opens the file for a fresh write; thus it destroys anything written to that file before.

Try:

```
ff=open('array.txt','w')
for i in range(3):
    z = np.ones((3,5))*i
    np.savetxt(ff,z)
```

This should write 9 lines, with 5 columns

I was going to adapt your:

```
  for r in range(0,rows):
      for c in range(0,cols):
          z=np.matrix(input())
          np.savetxt...
```

But that doesn't make sense.  You don't write by 'column' with `savetxt`.

Go to a Python interpreter, make a simple array (not `np.matrix`), and save it.  Make several arrays and save those.  Look at what you saved.

Comment: instead of using  z = np.ones((3,5))*i  can i use z=np.matrix(input()) bcoz i want to take generalize input from the user.

Comment: i m trying to implement sample example for back-propagation algorithm from artificial neural network using python.so i tried above code for taking inputs for the neurons.i want to make it generalize code

Comment: `np.matrix(input())` may work because `matrix` accepts a MATLAB like string expression.  But it is not normally used in `numpy`.  And since you are quite new to `numpy` I would not recommend going that route.